# Half-Life Dedicated Server Error. Unable to load engine, image is corrupt. Windows 7

Tags: counter-strike, source-engine

I want to make a Counter-Strike 1.6 dedicated server. When I run hlds.exe it shows this error:

> Half-Life Dedicated Server Error. Unable to load engine, image is corrupt. Windows 7

I tried three different counter strike but same error. Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: Humpf... Have you tried re-downloading? Are you using a custom build? I think we need some more information...

Comment: i tried three different copies. Can you provide orginal link ?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to install the Counter Strike 1.6 dedicated server is by using Valve's [hldsupdatetool](http://www.steampowered.com/download/hldsupdatetool.exe) and using the command line to update/install the server directly from Steam.

1. Download [hldsupdatetool](http://www.steampowered.com/download/hldsupdatetool.exe) from Valve
2. Create a directory to hold your server files, such as C:\cstrike16
3. Copy hldsupdatetool.exe into this folder
4. Open a command prompt
5. Change directory to your server directory (ie, "cd C:\cstrike16"
6. Run hldsupdatetool to download the server files:

> hldsupdatetool.exe -command update -game cstrike -dir .

You might have to run this command a couple of times, as Valve frequently updates their update tool.  When the update tool's out of date, you'll update the tool instead of the dedicated server files.  I know at least on Linux the updater downloads a differently named updater (ie, the command changes from hldsupdatetool to steam) so watch the updater's output carefully.

There's also a pretty good guide with screenshots on [CStrike Planet](http://www.cstrike-planet.com/tutorial/1-Windows-Install-CS-16/4) if this isn't enough to get you going.